# Javascript, pegar um numero (cep) dentro de uma faixa de uma cidade

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho uma lista de CEP de cidades que um convênio atende (vende). por exemplo:
Campinas faixa de cep de campinas 13000001 a 13139999, Araras de 13600001 a 13609999.
Precisava criar um IF Else assim para um input do mue formulario:
Obs.: Se que o código está errado ai em baixo, foi mesmo pra ilustrar, pode ser em JS ou Jquery.

```
var campinas (13000001 a 13139999);
var araras (13600001 a 13609999);
if (valor digitado estiver na faixa dos cep de Campinas ou Araras) {
   alert("Cobrimos sua área");
} else {
   alert("Não atendemos a área de seu CEP");
}
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="cep" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suponho que você já tenha um modo de obter o valor do cep escrito no input e colocado em uma variável que aqui chamaremos di `cep`;

```
// Remove tudo da string deixando somente os numeros e converte a mesma em um inteiro
var cleanCep = parseInt(cep.replace(/\D+/g, ''));
```

E digamos que você tenha um array de objetos com as cidades que são aceitas:

```
var cidades = [
  {nome: 'Campinas', cMin: 13000001, cMax: 13139999},
  {nome: 'Araras', cMin: 13600001, cMax: 13609999},
];
```

cMin e cMax estão para cep minimo e maximo.

Agora vamos verificar se uma das cidades estão no range do CEP inserido usando o método [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

```
// O metodo find irá retornar o primeiro elemento do seu array que condiz com a condição inserida
var cidade = cidades.find((cd) => cleanCep >= cd.cMin && cleanCep <= cd.cMax);
```

Apos isso basta verificar se a variável cidade `contém` um valor

```
if(cidade){
   // Se o cep estiver no range, o valor da variável cidade será a primeira cidade que fez match com a expressão usada no método `find`
   console.log(`A cidade ${cidade.nome} é aceita`);
} else {
   console.error(`Cidade não suportada`);
}
```

Comment: Leo segue abaixo minha dúvida.

Answer (score 0):

Leo obrigado pelo retorno.
Não sei se entendi, mas deu erro, olha o que coloquei:

```
<script>
            
    function validaCobertura(){
    var cep = parseFloat(document.getElementById("cep").value);
            
          var cidades = [
               {nome: 'Campinas', cMin: 13000001, cMax: 13139999},
               {nome: 'Araras', cMin: 13140000, cMax: 13140999},
          ];
    
          var cidade = cidades.find((cd) => cleanCep >= cd.cMin && cleanCep <= cd.cMax);
    
          if(cidade){
                console.log('A cidade ${cidade.nome} é aceita');
           } else {
                console.error('Cidade não suportada');
           }     
            
    }
    
</script>
```

Html:

```
<input type="text" id="cep" placeholder="cep" />
<button onclick="validaCobertura()">Exibir Cep</button>
```

Comment: olhe dentro ao método find tem `cleanCep` como variável, mas você salvou o valor do seu input em uma variável chamada `cep`

Comment: Aqui um [exemplo](https://jsfiddle.net/92h8ct0f/) de como você pode fazer

Comment: Valeu Leo Letto, obrigado.